# SQL UPDATE Query With values of another table column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are three tables

```
Email  
ID  
10  
11  
12  

SLA_DATE     
ID    |    Email_ID  
21    |    10  
22    |    11  
23    |    12  

SLA    
ID    |    Email_ID  
33    |    10  
34    |    11  
35    |    12
```

I am trying to update the SLA Email_ID  from Email.ID to SLA_DATE.ID.
So, after updating the SLA, the table should look like

```
SLA    
ID    |    Email_ID  
33    |    21  
34    |    22  
35    |    23
```

Below is what i have tried so far..

```
UPDATE SLA SET 
SLA.Email_ID = SLA_DATE.ID WHERE SLA_DATE.Email_ID = SLA_EMAIL_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Email_ID = d.ID
FROM SLA s
INNER JOIN
SLA_DATE d
    ON d.Email_ID = s.Email_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Update S SET S.EmailID = D.ID
   From SLA A
   Join SLA_DATE D On D.Email_ID = S.Email_ID
```